# Variational inference: how to rewrite ELBO?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, expectation-maximization, conditional-expectation, variational-bayes

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00670.pdf) on variational inference and [this website](https://am207.github.io/2017/wiki/VI.html#elbo---evidence-lower-bound---objective-function-to-be-optimized).

One thing I am confused about is how they get to decompose ELBO, where $ELBO(q) = E_q[log~p(z,x)] - E_q[log~q(z)]$, when focusing on one latent variable's variational distribution $q_j$ like this:

$$
ELBO(q_j) = E_j[E_{-j}[log~p(z_j, z_{-j}, x)]] - E_j[log~q_j(z_j)] + C
$$

They say that they use [iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) but I had a hard time decomposing $ELBO(q_j)$ using that ($E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$).

Can anyone elaborate on this? Thanks!

**UPDATE**: $q(z)=\prod_{i} q(z_i)$ is an assumption so I understand the decomposition of the 2nd term.

Answer (score 1):

Your update has stated that you are using the mean-field variational family, or in other words that $q(z)=\prod_{i} q(z_i)$ which means that
$$
\log q(z) = \sum_i \log q(z_i) \tag{*}.
$$

So
\begin{align*}
\text{ELBO}(q) &= E_q[\log p(z,x)] - E_q[\log q(z)] \\
&= E_q[\log p(z_j, z_{-j},x)] - E_q[\log q(z_j, z_{-j})] \\
&= E_q[\log p(z_j, z_{-j},x)] - E_q[\log q(z_j) + \sum_{i\neq j}\log q(z_i)] \tag{*}\\
&= E_q[E\left(\log p(z_j, z_{-j},x) \mid z_{j} \right)] - E_q[\log q(z_j)] - E\left[\sum_{i\neq j}\log q(z_i)\right].\\
\end{align*}
This is equivalent to equation (19) in your first linked document.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The last equality confuses me a bit: you said that the outer expectation is taken w.r.t. $z$ or $z_{j}$. But according to the law iterated expectation, the outer expectation should be taken w.r.t. $Y$, which is $z_{-j}$ here. Shouldn't the first term be $E_q [E_q[log~p(z_j, z_{-j}, x) \vert z_{j}]]$?

Comment: I am still confused. Why the equation above has the same term on both the RHS and LHS?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I could not get your idea. I figured out one understanding below. Let me know if you think that's appropriate or not if you have time. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zhiya looks good!

Answer (score 0):

I read those two materials again and think that the decomposition may be done via the following rearrangement:

\begin{align}
ELBO & = E_q[log~p(x,z)] - E_q[log~q(z)] \\
& = E_q[log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j})] - \sum_{q_l}E_{q_l}[q_l(z_l)] \\
& [\text{Here we use the fact that } q(z) \text{ can be factorized}]\\
& = E_j\Big[E_{-j}\big[ log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j}) \vert z_{j} \big] \Big] -
 E_{q_j}[q_j] + const \\
\end{align}

Now, according to the definition of expectation, we have:
\begin{align}
E_{-j}\big[ log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j}) \vert z_{j} \big] &= \int_{-j} log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j})~q(z_{-j}|z_j) dq_{-j} \\
& = \int_{-j} log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j})~q(z_{-j}) dq_{-j} \\
& = E_{-j}\big[ log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j}) \big]
\end{align}
[We assume independence between latent variables' variational distributions $q(z)$]

Therefore we have:

$$ELBO = E_{-j}\big[ log~p(x, z_j, z_{-j}) \big] - E_{q_j}[q_j] + const $$