# Derivation of Variational Inference

Tags: variational-bayes

I'm reading [Blei et al. (2017) "Variational Inference: A Review for Statisticians"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.00670) to understand Variational Inference (VI). I follow the paper's notations: $\mathbf{x}_{1:n}$ (observations), $\mathbf{z}_{1:m}$ (latent variables), and $q(\mathbf{z})$ (a variational factors)
$$ q(\mathbf{z}) = \prod_{j=1}^{m} q_j(z_j).$$

On page 10, the paper explains how to get optimal $q_j(z_j)$. The log-likelihood of the observations is
$$
\log p(\mathbf{x}) = {\rm KL}( q(\mathbf{z}) || p(\mathbf{z} | \mathbf{x} ) ) + {\rm ELBO}(q) .
$$
We can decompose ELBO as
$$
{\rm ELBO}(q) = \mathbb{E}[ \log p(\mathbf{z}, \mathbf{x})] - \mathbb{E}[\log q(\mathbf{z})].
$$

Using a factorization assumption, we can focus on the $j$th variational factor $q_j(z_j)$
$$
{\rm ELBO}(q_j) = \mathbb{E}_j \left[ \mathbb{E}_{-j} [\log p(z_j, \mathbf{z}_{-j}, \mathbf{x})] \right] - \mathbb{E}_j \left[ \log q_j (z_j) \right] + const \ \ ({\rm Eq.A})
$$

From here, the paper claims we can get Eq.(18) (p.9)
$$
q_j^{*}(z_j) \propto \exp \left\{ \mathbb{E}_{-j} \left[ \log p(z_j, \mathbf{z}_{-j}, \mathbf{x})  \right]   \right\}.
$$

Since we want to maximize the ELBO with respect to $q_j$, we rewrite Eq.A as
$$
\left[ \int q(z_j) \left( \int q(\mathbf{z}_{-j}) \cdot \log p(z_j, \mathbf{z}_{-j}, \mathbf{x})  d\mathbf{z}_{-j}  \right) d z_j \right] - \left[ \int q(z_j) \log q(z_j) d z_j  \right] + const \ \ \ ({\rm Eq.B})
$$
and get
$$
\frac{\rm Eq.B}{\partial q(z_j)} = \left[ \int \int q(\mathbf{z}_{-j}) \log p(z_j, \mathbf{z}_{-j}, \mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{z}_{-j} dz_j \right] - \int \log q(z_j) dz_j + const \ \ ({\rm Eq.C})
$$

If we can say 
$$
{\rm Eq.C} = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{z}_{-j}} \left[ \log p (z_j, \mathbf{z}_{-j}, \mathbf{x}) \right] - \log q(z_j) + const, \ \ ({\rm Eq.D)}
$$
we can set ${\rm Eq.C}= 0$ and get Eq.(18) in the original paper.

However, I cannot derive it. For the first term, $p(z_j, \mathbf{z}_{-j}, \mathbf{x})$ has $\mathbf{z}_{-j}$ and $z_j$, and for the second term $q(z_j)$ has $z_j$. Don't we have to consider them when we calculate integral (expectation)?

Note:
I think my question is similar to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328203/variational-inference-how-to-rewrite-elbo), but I have a trouble with how to get Eq.(18) in the original paper while the linked post focuses on how to get Eq.A.

Comment: Don't take partials (he mentions you can derive it this way, but you don't actually have to). You can write out the elbo for one of the components of the variational distribution $q_j$ as a negative KL-divergence between $q_j$ and some other distribution. Find this distribution, set $q_j$ to it (which will make the KL-divergence 0) and you'll arrive at 18.

Comment: @marmleThanks.  In that case, where the $\propto$ comes in? If we focus on terms other than constant in Eq.(19), we can get a negative KL divergence $-{\rm KL} (q(z_j) || p(z_j, \mathbf{x}))$. How can I move from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$\textsf{ELBO}(q_j)=\mathbb{E}_{q_j}[\mathbb{E}_{q_{-j}}[\log(p(z_j,z_{-j},x))]]-\mathbb{E}_{q_j}[\log(q_j(z_j))]-constant,$$
which we can rewrite as
$$\textsf{ELBO}(q_j)=-\mathbb{E}_{q_j}\left[\log\left(\frac{q_j(z_j)}{\exp\left[\mathbb{E}_{q_{-j}}[\log(p(z_j,z_{-j},x))]\right]}\right)\right]-constant,$$
which we recognize as a KL divergence (up to a constant)
$$\textsf{ELBO}(q_j)=-D_{KL}\left(q_j(z_j)||\exp\left[\mathbb{E}_{q_{-j}}[\log(p(z_j,z_{-j},x))]\right]\right)-constant.$$

Since we'd like to maximize the $\textsf{ELBO}$, we'd like to minimize the KL divergence. This happens when we let 
$q_j(z_j)\propto\exp\left[\mathbb{E}_{q_{-j}}[\log(p(z_j,z_{-j},x))]\right]$.

The reason we only specify this up to a constant of proportionality is because we were being a little sloppy before! That technically wasn't a KL divergence since $\exp\left[\mathbb{E}_{q_{-j}}[\log(p(z_j,z_{-j},x))]\right]$ wasn't normalized (we can just add in the normalizing constant since it won't depend on $z_j$ and thus we'll still have the same optimization problem, so this isn't too important).

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last paragraph in detail? Particularly, I am not sure why the exponential part is not normalized.

Comment: Also, why can we ignore the $\log$ in $\log (q_j (z_j))$ when we go from the second equation to the third in your answer? Can't we remove $\log$ in the second equation?

Comment: That log is a typo, thanks for catching it! And as for the last paragraph, why would it be normalized? We're taking the log of a density, taking an expectation, then exponentiating. Why would the result of that end up integrating to 1 in general? You can look at the section where they derive the updates for an exponential family to see an example of what the exponential part might look like for an actual model.