# In MAP, does maximizing the posterior minimize any divergence between distributions?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, estimation, posterior, divergence

It's known that maximizing the log-likelihood is equivalent to minimizing the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the model $q(x \mid \theta)$ and the unknown true data generating distribution $p(x)$:

$$
\begin{split}
\hat{\theta}_{\mathrm{ML}} &= \arg\min_{\theta} \mathrm{KL}(p(x) \mid\mid q(x \mid \theta)) =
 \arg\min_{\theta} \left[ \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p} \ln p(X) - \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p} \ln q(X \mid\theta) \right]\\
&= \arg\min_{\theta} \left[ \mathrm{const} - \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p} \ln q(X \mid\theta) \right]\\
&= \arg\max_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_{X \sim p} \ln q(X \mid\theta)
\approx \arg\max_{\theta} \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N \ln q(x_n \mid\theta)
\end{split}
$$

Is there anything similar for *maximum a posteriori* (MAP) estimation? **EDIT**: by "similar" I mean "something that involves a divergence between *distributions* (PDFs, CDFs, characteristic functions, etc), not *values* of $\theta$". Is MAP equivalent to minimization of some *divergence between distributions* that depend on $\theta$? Maybe some distributions *of* $\theta$, like the KL divergence for MLE as shown above?

Given the posterior:

$$
f(\theta \mid X) = \frac{q(X \mid \theta) r(\theta)}{\int_{\Theta} q(X \mid \theta) r(\theta) d\theta}
$$

...does maximizing it $f(\theta \mid X) \to \max_{\theta}$ minimize some kind of divergence between some *distributions*, similar to how MLE minimizes the KL divergence?

I know the KL divergence between $f(\theta \mid X)$ and an approximation $f(\theta)$ is used in [variational inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328626/derivation-of-variational-inference), but there we're looking for the entire approximate posterior $f(\theta)$, while MAP is for point estimates.

The usual reasoning for MAP seems to be "maximize the posterior to find its mode, which is the most probable/likely/common value of $\theta$", but I'm wondering whether MAP can be derived as a minimizer of some distance/divergence between *distributions*, not values of the parameters $\theta$.

**EDIT**: comments below point out that the median can be derived as a minimum distance solution. However, this distance is defined for the parameter space $\Theta$, while I'm looking for an interpretation that involves distances/divergences between *probability distributions*.

Comment: Nothing special about the posterior except in a MAP context.  Your question is really what is minimised by the mode of a distribution.

Comment: Suppose $m_k$ minimises $\mathbb E\left[|\Theta-m_k|^k\right]$ so $m_1$ is the median of the distribution for $\Theta$, and $m_2$ is the mean.  Then consider $\lim\limits_{k \to 0^+} m_k$.  In my view this is not a convincing cost measure, especially if the distribution is continuous

Comment: @Henry, I'm wondering whether there's a different approach that _doesn't_ directly involve the mode. Say, maximizing the likelihood is often motivated as looking for a $\theta$ which makes the data $\{x_n\}$ most "likely". The point of view of KL divergence doesn't have to mention this and involves minimizing information loss. You could generalize this to other divergences and distances and arrive at minimum distance estimation. So, we get a view of MLE which doesn't involve maximizing the likelihood. I'm asking if there's anything similar for MAP, something that doesn't involve modes.

Comment: @ForceBru the answer of Henry does not involve modes directly. They're pointing out that there's a sense in which the mode minimizes $\ell_0$ loss; see here for more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329908/under-the-0-1-loss-function-the-bayesian-estimator-is-the-mode-of-the-posterior

Comment: @JohnMadden, yes, the mode, median, mean, variance all minimize something, sure. Does this mean that Bayesian point estimation always/often uses distances on the _parameter_ space $\Theta$ as opposed to distances/divergences between _distributions_ $p$ and $q$ used by MLE and minimum divergence estimators? I was hoping for an answer that viewed MAP as a solution to a minimum divergence problem, such that $\theta_{\mathrm{MAP}}$ minimized a distance between _distributions_, not the random variable $\Theta$ and a number/vector. This could be impossible, hence the question.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah im not sure, but one thing I would point out is that the MAP is only very tenuously a Bayesian point estimate.